# I want to display the column names which are correlated >0.75

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a dataframe and i have run df.corr().by this i got the correlation matrix.I want to display only the column names where the correlation between columns is greater than 0.75.can anyone plz help me out in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the cleanest solution, but maybe you could try:

```
corr = df.corr()
corr = corr[(corr>0.75)&(corr<1)].dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me but is there any possibility of displaying column names in form of list like this [col1,clo3][col4,col2].......